# Running a Java Applet in webkit in Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webkit

I am trying to make a simple browser to load a page that contains a Java Applet (the webpage is not mine) using WebKitBrowser , but it just crashes with error.

```
exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
```

Is WebKitBrowser compatible to load Java Applet at all? if yes how do I fix the error? if no any alternatives besides default IE WebBrowser?

Comment: Have you tried any other applets?

Comment: Just did that now and I get the same error.